im having a problem in @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object
Whenever I try compile my code for older browsers it Babel doesn't work properly
Whenever I try compile https://github.com/zeondev/pluto down to work with older browsers I get this really annoying error from babel that is an actual error in the code.
It looks like this
SyntaxError: E:\pluto_babel\src\node_modules\@babel\plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object\lib\index.js: 'return' outside of function. (25:2)

  23 |   `);
  24 |
> 25 |   return;
     |   ^
  26 | } catch (e) {}
  27 |
  28 | throw new Error(`\
    at constructor (E:\pluto_babel\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:351:19)
    at Parser.raise (E:\pluto_babel\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:3233:19)
    at Parser.parseReturnStatement (E:\pluto_babel\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12597:12)
    at Parser.parseStatementContent (E:\pluto_babel\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12254:21)
    at Parser.parseStatementLike (E:\pluto_babel\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12223:17)
    at Parser.parseStatementListItem (E:\pluto_babel\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12203:17)
    at Parser.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (E:\pluto_babel\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12780:61)
    at Parser.parseBlockBody (E:\pluto_babel\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12773:10)
    at Parser.parseBlock (E:\pluto_babel\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12761:10)
    at Parser.parseTryStatement (E:\pluto_babel\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12669:23) {
  code: 'BABEL_PARSE_ERROR',
  reasonCode: 'IllegalReturn',
  loc: Position { line: 25, column: 2, index: 1133 },
  pos: 1133
}

Im running it using
babel src --out-dir dist
and my babel rc looks like
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "safari": "9"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}


Can anyone help?
This is web because im trying to make online javascript more compatible
